# Trying to inject to a Job class

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, dagger-2

I have a network component in my app that allows me to inject retrofit to my activities & fragments , i wanted to inject it to my Job class , here's what i did

NetComponent interface :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
    void inject(SplashActivity activity);
    void inject(RegisterActivity activity);
     void inject(SettingsFragment fragment);
     void inject(Context cont); // also tried void inject(Job job);
}
```

And in my Job Class i inject it like this :

```
public class LogUploader extends Job {
    public static final String TAG = "UPLOAD_LOGS" ;
    @Inject
    Retrofit mRetrofitClient;
    @Override
    @NonNull
    protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {
        ((MyApp) getContext()).getNetComponent().inject(getContext());

        // run your job here
        Log.e("LogFile", "    "+  TAG);
         //// TODO: 10/18/2017 send log
        checklogs(this.getContext());
        //// TODO: 10/18/2017 get phone db update
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

And the crash :

```
ClassCastException: com.evernote.android.job.v21.PlatformJobService cannot be cast to com.**.**.Application.MyApp
```

Any ideas what should i do differently ? 
Thanks to all the helpers !

**UPDATE**

The first crash (CCE) was because I did getContext and cast it to MyApp , I changed it to

```
((MyApp) this.getContext().getApplicationContext()).getNetComponent().inject(getContext());
```

Now the crash makes more sense :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object retrofit2.Retrofit.create(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference
```

I checked with the debug , the inject line doesn't inject mRetrofitClient

Any ideas ?

NetModule class :

```
@Module

public class NetModule {
    String mBaseUrl;

    // Constructor needs one parameter to instantiate.
    public NetModule(String baseUrl) {
        this.mBaseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    // Dagger will only look for methods annotated with @Provides
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    // Application reference must come from AppModule.class
    SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Application application) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Cache provideOkHttpCache(Application application) {
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
        Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
        return cache;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);

        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Cache cache) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().cache(cache).build();
        return client;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())

                .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add you retrofit provide logic.

Comment: added the whole net module, thanks

Comment: please provide the full stack trace of your NPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it by changing

```
 void inject(Context cont);
```

to

```
 void inject(LogUploader  lp);
```

and in the LogUploader to

```
        ((MyApp) this.getContext().getApplicationContext()).getNetComponent().inject(this);
```

I tried it before without the getApplicationContext which was the first crash , after the changes it works .

Basically the inject needs to get the class that you want to inject doesn't matter if it's Activity Fragment or any other.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, since the Job has not been created yet in the constructor, you'll get an error.

You'll need to place this code snippet in `onRunJob()` method before any other code.

```
((MyApp) this.getContext().getApplicationContext()).getNetComponent().inject(this);
```